# How to place a subview in the center of parent view using .center?

Tags: ios, swift, center, subview, frames

I have two subviews: the purple one belongs to a main view and it works wonderful with the syntax:

```
sSubview.center = view.center
```

The orange one belongs to the purple view and the same syntax doesn't place it correctly in the center.
Could you see where my mistake is?

```
Here is my code:

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var sSubview = UIView()
var sLabel = UILabel()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    createSimplestSubview()

}

// First subview

func createSimplestSubview() {
 sSubview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width * 0.9, height: view.frame.height * 0.9))
 sSubview.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple // just for test, to make it visible
 sSubview.center = view.center // that s pretty easy!

 view.addSubview(sSubview)
 createSimplestLabel()
 }

// Second subview

func createSimplestLabel() {

    sLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sSubview.frame.width * 0.3, height: sSubview.frame.height * 0.2))
    sLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange // just for test, to make it visible
    sLabel.center = sSubview.center
    sLabel.text = "This label has to be centered!"
    sLabel.textAlignment = .center
    sLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    sSubview.addSubview(sLabel)

}
```

}

Here is a screen:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the next code for seconds subview:

```
sLabel.center = CGPoint(x: sSubview.frame.width / 2, y: sSubview.frame.height / 2)
```

You're trying to place a label in the center, but it calculated according to the firstSbuview frame, which origin is not 0.0

Answer (score 3):

A better way is to use `convertPoint` as the problem with your code is that the coordinate spaces are sometimes different.

```
sSubview.center = view.superview.convert(view.center, to: sSubview.superview)
```

`view.center` is in the coordinate space of `view.superview`

`sSubview.center` is in the coordinate space of `sSubview.superview`

Comment: It works, thank you! Only a small correction in your code: sSubview.center = (view.superview?.convert(view.center, to: sSubview.superview))! Perhaps, it is the newest version of swift :)

Comment: I wrote it from memory, sorry. I would use `guard let` instead of `!`